# How to get the row data in kendo grid onselect in Angular JS fromat

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, grid

I am refraining to use jquery here so don't mark this as duplicate.

Here is the sample running [Demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/aRuQubep).
Please help me to get the selected row data.

Comment: Given that I answered your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50601458/how-to-get-the-selected-radio-button-in-the-kendo-grid, is this still relevant?

Comment: Yea thanks! I can still use this so I can sync the radio button and clicking of the row! Big Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution.

You need to change html:

```
<kendo-grid options="mainGridOptions" k-on-change="onChange(dataItem)">
            </div>
            </kendo-tabstrip>
        </div>
    </kendo-grid>
```

And Javascript:

```
$scope.onChange = function(newrow){

        console.log(newrow);
      }
```

Here is also a working Dojo. Hope this helps you.
https://dojo.telerik.com/@sehaxx/uyiZazeW

Cheers,