# How to get the selected radio button in the Kendo Grid

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid with a column consisting of radio buttons.
I want to make the radio buttons act as radio buttons(check only 1) and get the selected 1.

Here is a sample [Demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/aRuQubep/4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were pretty close. First a few things about radios:

- Radio buttons are grouped using the `name` attribute
- Radio buttons are bound to labels via the `for` attribute on the label element matched with the `id` attribute on the radio button

The problem with your code is that all radios have the same `id`, which is why clicking any radio button toggles the first one ... because the first element found with that id is grabbed, with the assumption that there'd only be one.

In order to fix this, you need a unique id for each radio button, and you can do that by referencing the EmployeeID in the data source using the `#: EmployeeID#` notation, as exemplified in the [docs](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.template)

Therefore your template would look like this:

```
template: '<input type="radio" name="customer" id="customer_#: EmployeeID#" class="k-radio"><label class="k-radio-label" for="customer_#: EmployeeID#"></label>'
```

Please find working example here: https://dojo.telerik.com/aRuQubep/5

Hope this does the job :)

Comment: Oh Thanks! worked! what if i wanna get the selected EmployeeID with a button?

Comment: Can you please expand? Get it for what? After what action do you want to get the id? etc.

Comment: I should add a button sorry I forgot to add a button to the demo where I can get the 1 select ID. Thanks!

Comment: if this resolved the issue mentioned in the title, please mark this as accepted response :)